# SQL Server 2008 R2: How do I "pause" a clustered index while the server is being written to?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm wondering if its possible to "pause" a clustered index whenever bulk data is being written?

The reason is that:

- Bulk inserts are slow (**10,000** rows/second) if I have a clustered index on "DateTime".
- Bulk inserts are fast (**180,000** rows/second) if I have an inactive clustered index on "DateTime".

I don't mind if the clustered index is rebuilt overnight, e.g. from 1am to 6am.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***You can't disable a clustered index and still use the table.***

Since the clustered index **IS THE TABLE** having it disabled means you can't access any of the data.

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177456.aspx)

> The data rows of the disabled clustered index cannot be accessed except to drop or rebuild the clustered index.

You can...

- disable any nonclustered indexes and rebuild them overnight.  This will help greatly
- `DROP` all indexes (including clustered) and insert, then `CREATE` them overnight.  This will render the table basically unusable, though.

My preferred solution for  this is a little more complicated:

- `INSERT` into a staging table that has the same clustered index key as your target table
- `INSERT` from staging into target overnight and update indexes as needed then

Comment: Quote: "DROP all indexes (including clustered) and insert, then CREATE them overnight. This will render the table basically unusable, though.". Not quite correct - I used horizontal partitioning to get around this: partition by DateTime, and a query on 200 million rows finishes in 5 seconds.

Comment: @Gravitas Partitioning is a whole different animal that you didn't bring up in the OP.  But yes, that is a workaround (and one of the advantages of partitioning).

Comment: As an aside - is it possible to pause a non-clustered index?

Comment: @Gravitas nope.  The clustered index is the table.  It's just a framework to physically order the data pages by the clustered index key.  If  you "disable" or "ignore" it, then the engine doesn't know where to put the data!  In a table with no clustered index you would have a RID (row ID) to point to, but in a clustered table it needs to go by the clustered key.  If this is not maintained then nothing can be read or written.

Comment: Imagine a phone book where you weren't sure if any of the people's names were actually correct, to get an idea.